# App hangs when adding a large number of documents to Firestore (e.g. 1000+ documents) at once

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to allow a user to mass add a bunch of documents to Firestore from the client side. It works fine when there aren't that many documents but when there a ton (e.g. 1000+ documents), it adds all of the documents and then just hangs. If I close and then reopen the app, I see that all of the documents have been added as desired.

I am adding each document one by one using the following:

```
self.collection.document(noteID).setData(record.dictionary)
```

Is there a reason why this would hang after mass adding a bunch of documents but work fine on smaller sets? Is there a way to batch add a bunch of documents to Firestore so that they don't hang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happends because each write is generating a transaction that need to be executed, and your app hangs as it is waiting for each transaction to respond.

to write tons of documents in one action the recomendation in the official documentatipon is to use [Batch Writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes).

Just take in consideration that each batch can take up tpo 500 writes.

to Add data on Batch writes you can do it like this:

```
let batch = self.batch()

//set Documents to add 
let doc1 = self.collection(<COLLECTION>).document(noteID)
batch.setData(record.dictionary, forDocument: doc1)

//commit the batch
batch.commit() { err in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error writing batch \(err)")
    } else {
        print("Batch write succeeded.")
    }
}
```